# Android: Unable to detect vertical plane

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to detect a vertical plane like wall to add image view on a vertical plane. But did not find the vertical plane. As per the default config for a session that can find both planes as a horizontal and vertical plane. But unable to find a vertical plan.

How to find a vertical plane in android application?

Please help me.

Comment: Maybe you can visualize the feature points and check if your  vertical plane has enough features to be detected.

Answer (score 4):

In ARCore and ARKit, tracking of vertical surfaces is a bit more difficult to achieve than tracking of horizontal surfaces. Firstly, all you need is an ***appropriate*** surface for tracking. Wall with a solid color (with no distinguishing features on it) is very bad sample. The best sample for tracking of a vertical surface is a well-lit brick wall, or a wall with pictures on it, etc. The worst sample for tracking is a solid-color wall, or wall with repetitive texture pattern (like polka dot), or reflective/refractive surface.

The same principles apply to horizontal tracking.

[image]

Secondly, the easiest way of creating an `Anchor` in the center of your detected plane is to use the following code (make sure you call it once, so it couldn't create a new `Anchor` on every update):

```
Anchor newAnchor;

for (Plane plane : mSession.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {

    if (plane.getType() == Plane.Type.VERTICAL &&
        plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {

        newAnchor = plane.createAnchor(plane.getCenterPose());
        break;
    }
}
```