# ARCore Surface Detection based on Image from Gallery

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

i want to make surface detection like in this video [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLDczYMVF3o). But, i dont want to realtime, i want to detect by image like [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homedepot.ca%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fhomedepot%2Fimages%2Fcategories%2Ffloors%2Fvinyl-flooring%2Fjan-2019-clp-vinyl-flooring-900x600.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homedepot.ca%2Fen%2Fhome%2Fcategories%2Ffloors%2Fvinyl-flooring.html&docid=o3yRi035UBAuHM&tbnid=80z4Da_xF-WyVM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjczu_yqrTlAhUPXisKHVrxD4YQMwh_KAMwAw..i&w=900&h=600&safe=strict&bih=625&biw=1360&q=floor&ved=0ahUKEwjczu_yqrTlAhUPXisKHVrxD4YQMwh_KAMwAw&iact=mrc&uact=8). Example implemented you can check [Here](https://residential.torlys.com/discover/visualizer/) Do you guys have tutorial or can you give me some advice? Thanks before

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Surface detection in an image from your gallery? That would be impossible. ARCore only works using your Android device camera in real time.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to decorate the floor with the "image" when the ARCore is detecting the surface?

Comment: detection not on gallery, i just want to take picture from gallery. Of course detection on the app.

Answer (score 0):

ARCore doesn't detect surfaces based on single images. It uses a stream of images, plus information from other sensors, like the gyroscope.

Some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356589/what-sensors-does-arcore-use).

For surface detection in images you can look at other libraries, like [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/detection_of_planar_objects/detection_of_planar_objects.html).