# ARCore – Raw Depth Data from rear Android depth camera

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, depth-buffer

I can't figure out how can I get raw depth data from my Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro with rear ToF depth sensor.

I've tried:

- Camera2Format from [android samples](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2Formats). No results (and [I'm not alone](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/99))
- get physicalId from rear camera as described in [android developers blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/getting-the-most-from-the-new-multi-camera-api-5155fb3d77d9). No result.
- ARCore API [can't handle depth](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/120).

I saw several similar questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494608/how-to-get-depth-map-in-android-q), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738470/androidq-how-to-access-dynamic-depth-format)) without answers. Is it so difficult to capture raw depth from depth camera in Android?

Comment: If you look at the end of this discussion there is modified version of Camera2RawFragment which the author uses to access the DEPTH image data: https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/forum/#!topic/camerax-developers/iI-O5tWxiZs. Hopefully, this helps although its worth reading the full thread on the accuracy of the data.

Answer (score 2):

### Raw Depth API vs Full Depth API

At Google I/O 2021, the [Raw Depth API](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/raw-depth) for ARCore 1.24 version was announced in addition to the existing [Full Depth API](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/introduction), working since ARCore 1.18. This second-Gen depth API gives you the ability to merge Raw Depth data coming from iToF sensor with data coming from `Depth-from-Motion` ML-algorithm. The resulted data can be retrieved through 16-bit buffer stream, where 13-bit is reserved for `depth map` and 3-bit is reserved for `confidence map`.

At Google I/O 2022, `Full Depth API` was updated for users running ARCore 1.31. Now, all 16 bits per pixel are used, allowing app to represent the depth within a distance of 65,535 millimeters.

[image]

Today ARCore developers can use Raw Depth API for Precise Measurements and for ops on Reconstructed Mesh. On the other hand, Full Depth API is ideally suitable for People/Objects Occlusion and Scene Relighting purposes.

The following table represents three important parameters:

|  | Full Depth API (v1.31+) | Raw Depth API (v1.24+) | Full Depth API (v1.18+) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Accuracy | Bad | Awesome | Bad |
| Coverage | All pixels | Not all pixels | All pixels |
| Distance | 0 to 65.5 m | 0.5 to 5.0 m | 0 to 8.2 m |

> Raw Depth is available on all devices that support the Depth API. The Raw Depth API, like the Full Depth API, does not require a supported hardware depth sensor, such as a time-of-flight (iToF) sensor. However, both the Raw Depth API and the Full Depth API make use of any supported hardware sensors that a device may have.

The list of ARCore Depth API [supported devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/devices) is growing. Pay attention to the last column called `Comments` - info about Depth API support is there.