# Depth API supported devices

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I'd really like to develop some ARCore apps which use the new Google ARCore Depth API. But I realize that there are only couple of devices that support this new feature. So, is there any information about updates in the future which to support devices that are today supported by ARCore but not for Depth API?

For example:

The Pocophone F1 is officially supported for the Depth API. It uses MIUI as Operating System and run with a Snapdragon 845.

**Now is the question**: why nearly exactly the same devices as Xiaomi Mi Mix 2s or Xiaomi Mi 8 are not supported?

These three devices all use MIUI same Camera and same CPU so would these devices Support Depth API in the future?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly: there is a long list of devices that have ToF sensor and support [Raw Depth API](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/raw-depth) as well as [Full Depth API](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/introduction) for ARCore 1.24 at the moment. And I firmly believe there will be much more of them in the nearest future. You can see it in [ARCore supported devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) table.

- Google Pixel 2/3/4/5
- Huawei Honor 10/Nova 3,4/Mate 20,Lite,X/P20/P30/Pro
- LG ThinQ/G8X/V35/V50S/V60
- OnePlus OnePlus 6/T/7/Pro
- Samsung Galaxy A80/S8/S9/S10/S20/Note 8,9,10
- Sony Xperia XZ2/Compact/Premium/XZ3
- Xiaomi Pocophone F1

Secondly: ARCore's Depth API unsupported devices, seemingly don't have ToF sensor, or don't have powerful CPU/GPU for retrieving Depth data from Motion, or even don't have a gyroscope. Or in some case (like Huawei case) it's just Google's policy. OS and its UI don't matter.

For additional info on both ARCore Depth APIs, please look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088045/arcore-raw-depth-data-from-rear-android-depth-camera/67659926#67659926).

Answer (score -2):

google said single rgb camera is enough for depth api to work