# ARCore: not getting features points on white or any plain surface

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, arcore-limitation

I'm using ARCore in my Android app and required features points from ARCore. But I'm not able to get features points for the plain white surfaces. If I try it with a few objects on a surface or texture surface in that case it is working fine.

Is it ARCore limitation or is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You should probably provide a picture of what you mean by 'plain white surface' but generally if there aren't any edges/variations/features in a field then optical detection like ARCore is limited.  From: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/fundamentals `Because ARCore uses feature points to detect planes, flat surfaces without texture, such as a white wall, may not be detected properly.`

Comment: @Morrison Chang - 'plain white surface I mean vertical or horizontal surface without any texture or objects. as I read ARCore docs and a few blogs seem like it's an ARCore limitation.

Answer (score 1):

White textureless surfaces (or surfaces of any ***solid*** color) can't produce feature points, since such points can only be generated at the border of high-contrast textures or surfaces. There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. [For devices without iToF sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256147/android-unable-to-detect-vertical-plane/53260589#53260589)

- Track well-lit surfaces with rich high-contrast glare-free non-repetitive textures.

2. [For devices with iToF](https://medium.com/macoclock/arkit-911-scene-reconstruction-with-a-lidar-scanner-57ff0a8b247e)

- When you use iToF in ARCore (or LiDAR in ARKit), feature points are not important, because you have a tracked reconstructed mesh ready for raycasting.

Comment: "For devices with iToF" is good, but I think Android devices do not support Lidar.

Comment: iToF and dToF sensors have the same goal - scene reconstruction.